# Background color remains white for safari browser

Tags: html, css

I have to provide a background color (#eeeeee) to a readonly input field.

```css
.form-control[disabled], 
.form-control[readonly],
fieldset[disabled] .form-control {
    cursor: not-allowed;
    background-color: #eeeeee;
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input id="tagNumber" name="j_username" class="form-control" tabindex="1" data-enhance="false" data-role="none" value="" maxlength="241" autocomplete="off" readonly="" type="text">
```

This works fine in all the browsers except the safari browser.
In safari the background color remains white.
I have tried providing the background color via jquery and also by adding a specific class to the element at run time. Nothing seems to work. Plz help.

How it looks on non safari browsers:

[image]

How it looks on safari browsers:

[image]

Comment: It's working fine in my mac safari with grey background...which os u r used? or may be ur css will conflict with other css..

Comment: not working for me in iphone 5 and iphone 6

Comment: Try to add one line of the code: `background-color: -webkit-#eeeeee;`

Comment: The inner box shadow at the top tells me `-webkit-appearance: none;` would fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this it may works

```
# @media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
{
#safari { background-color:#eeeeee }
}
```

or try rgb in your background colour for eg:

rgb(238, 238, 238) for #eeeeee

```
background-color:rgb(238, 238, 238);
```